# Accessing a static member function of a nested class template

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

For academic purposes I'm reinventing the wheel a bit and try to write a HAL library. Now in designing it I encountered a compiler error that I do not understand.

```
template< class DRIVER, class PORT, class PIN >
class Instance
{
        Instance(){}
    public: 

        static void set(const bool val) 
      { 
        DRIVER::GPIOPeripheral<PORT, PIN>::set(val); 
      }
      // ...
};
```

The idea is that a driver class defines the 'how' and an GPIO class defines the, well, GPIO interface abstraction.

The driver class looks something like this:

```
class SOC_xyz 
{
    SOC_xyz(){};

public:
    template<class PORT, class PIN>
    class GPIOPeripheral
    {
        static void set(const bool val){ /* ... */ };
    }
};
```

The call in the actual code looks like this:

```
typedef Instance<SOC_t, PORT0_t, PIN0_t> GPIO0_0;
GPIO0_0::set(1);
```

Now the compiler gives me a

> error: expected primary-expression before ',' token

for the `Instance::set` function where the `DRIVER::GPIOPeripheral<PORT, PIN>` gets called. From my understanding it tries to tell me that the class-template-member addressing part is wrong but this is beyond my C++ knowledge. Is that, what I try to do, even possible?

Comment: Have you tried writing ```DRIVER::template GPIOPeripheral<PORT, PIN>::set(val);```?

Comment: In `GPIOPeripheral`, `set` seems to be private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> DRIVER::GPIOPeripheral<PORT, PIN>::set(val);
> ```

`DRIVER` is a type template parameter of the `Instance` class template, but the primary class template does not know anything of the dependent type `GPIOPeripheral` of the parameterized type `DRIVER`; it only knows that the latter is a type (`DRIVER` may not even be a class type).

As you are designing your primary class template to allow invoking a member function of a dependent class *template* of the parameterized type `DRIVER`, you need to tell this to the compiler:

```
DRIVER::template GPIOPeripheral<PORT, PIN>::set(val);
//      ^^^^^^^^
```

formally declaring that the [*dependent name*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) `GPIOPeripheral` of the `DRIVER` type template parameter of the `Instance` class template is a template.

> #### The `template` disambiguator for dependent names
>
> Similarly, in a template definition, a dependent name that is not a
> member of the current instantiation **is not considered to be a
> template name unless the disambiguation keyword `template` is used**
> or unless it was already established as a template name: [...]

---

Also, note that as you are declaring the `GPIOPeripheral` class template using the `class`, with default access modifier `private`, meaning the `set` member function is private and cannot be accessed from outside the (lexical) scope of the class template itself of a friend to it.

Comment: The `template` keyword did the trick. Thank you very much. It makes sense that the nature of the object/function to be called is specified. I assumed the compiler would deduct that from the actual call in the program.

As for the `private` issue: That is a artifact of me leaving out unhelpful code. The real code has the public statement in there.